# Table prefix for MySqlMembershipProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, asp.net-mvc, mysql-connector

I have MySqlMembershipProvider working with Asp.Net MVC. My question is how can I configure the table prefix... so instead of 'my_aspnet_' prefix on the tables, I want this to be either none or defined by me.

My web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=root;Password=*********;database=sparkSources" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>

<membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider"
         type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider,
           MySql.Web, Version=6.3.4.0, Culture=neutral,
           PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"
         autogenerateschema="true"
         tablePrefix="ss"
         connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
         enablePasswordReset="true"
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
         requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         passwordFormat="Hashed"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
         minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
         passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
         applicationName="sparkSources"
 />
  </providers>
</membership>

<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>

<roleManager enabled="false">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>

<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured I would look at the source and to my surprise, the "my_aspnet" table prefix is hard coded as of versoion 6.3.4. Changed all the "my_aspnet" prefixs and recompiling the connector worked - so if you really want to change the table prefix -- get ready for some source-diving.